# Running TriggerToolkit.app for first time: toolkit-local.com SSL cert expired?

Tags: ssl, trigger.io

I just installed `TriggerToolkit.app` on OSX. Running it for the first time opens a browser tab in Chrome to the URL `https://toolkit-local.com:38394/`, but the SSL cert is expired. It looks like the cert expired in December of 2013. How should I proceed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're running an older version of the Toolkit with an expired certificate.

You can download the latest version at: https://trigger.io/forge/toolkit/

You may need to restart it once after installation for it to update to the latest version.

(Edit) Context: toolkit.local points at 127.0.0.1 or localhost and serves content from the embedded webserver that ships with the toolkit.

Comment: Reloading fixed the issue, thanks. It's bizarre that `toolkit-local.com` DNS has an A record pointing to `127.0.0.1`!